# One selenium test automation project run on few environments

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, webdriver, azure-pipelines

I have a single test automation project with test scripts which is integrated with VSTS and jenkins. It means VSTS build step run Jenkins job and after this test scripts are running on remote machine, but I have hardcoded URL in my `driver.get(url just for test env, but I need run on dev or prod env)` method.

So my question is how to parameterize `driver.get(parameter)` method to still use this one project and run test scripts on many env not just on test env?

For example: If new build queued is on QA branch then run scripts on http://QAenv.app.com else if queued on PROD branch then run scripts on http://PRODenv.app.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about storing it in properties and reading it?

Example:

```
driver.get(System.getProperty("myPropertyKey", "http://myDefaultTestUrl"));
```

Comment: Could You give more details and some example?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding Jenkins Queue Job step/task, you can specify Job parameters.

[image]

For the example you provided, you can add a variable to the build definition and change the value per to predefined variables (e.g. Build.SourceBranch ), then specify the variable in Jenkins Queue Job step/task.

Regarding set variable value, you can use `Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=testvar;]testvalue`", more information, you can refer to: [Logging Commands](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md)

Comment: Ok but i'm not sure how it works. Is it possible to make something like this that in my get method i will type driver.get(take parameter from job parameters) and in this window job parameters type my test env url?